# Bimodal MaxEnt distributions?

Tags: maximum-entropy, bimodal

What kind of constrains give rise to bimodal distributions in the Maximum Entropy formalism? Are there any known results in this topic?

Answer (score 2):

This might be related to the support of the constraints. With the following notation: let `X` be a discrete random variable on `states`, let `P` be a probability distribution with `P(X=x_i)=p_i` for `i=1,...,n` where `n=length(states)`, and let `H(X)=-sum(p_i*log(p_i) for i=1,...,n)` be the entropy of `X`.

Define constraints by:

```
A_j: R^n -> R
```

as a column vector of length `n`, `j=1,...,m` and demand that the conditions

```
A_j %*% X == bvec[j]  for j=1,...,m
```

are satisfied.

Now if the constraints are supported on different subsets of `states`, a bimodal distribution may arise. For example:

```
n <- 40
p <- 0.5
mu <- n*p
A_1 <- c(1:n, rep(0,n))
A_2 <- c((1:n-mu)^2, rep(0,n))
A_3 <- c(rep(0,n), 1:n)
A_4 <- c(rep(0,n), (1:n-mu)^2)
bvec <- c(mu, n*p*(1-p), mu, n*p*(1-p))/2
```

The first two conditions result in a binomial distribution on `1:40` and the second two conditions result in a binomial distribution on `41:80`. The maximum entropy distribution on `states=1:80` has then two modi:

[image: maximum entropy distribution of the above constraints]

I believe this generalizes to continuous random variables.